# Linking files in C++

Tags: c++, static-linking

I'm trying to freshen up my basic C++ skills after a 2 year break by working on a basic card games program. So I created 3 objects: deck, hand, and card. Everything was working pretty well until I tried to define a global constant deck for the whole program to use and everything got screwed up (the deck is supposed to be all 52 cards in order and is never changed). I'm trying to figure out how to link the following files together:

```
main.cpp
deck.h
deck.cpp
hand.h
hand.cpp
card.h
card.cpp
```

Where do I need includes and also where and how do I define my global deck to be used across the program? I made a mess of my existing code to try to include everything in everything and now nothing is compiling correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Some error output would be invaluable to anyone motivated to solve your problem.

Comment: Without any real leads to go on, I predict that you forgot to add `extern` when you declared the global deck in a header.  In which case, every source file that includes that header will think they own a private static instance of the deck, rather than realising that they need to link to it later.

Answer (score 0):

For the deck, just define it in main.cpp. It can be passed by reference to any functions in other classes that would need to manipulate it. As far as headers, `#include` only the headers you need for the current source file. Including header guards is always a good idea as well, so you don't have to worry about how many times you reference a header.

*EDIT*

`extern` was mentioned in another answer. This is necessary if you're actually defining a global object. There are mixed opinions about globals. I've not seen it very often in pure C++.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about the global you would declare it as `extern` in deck.h (I'm assuming that makes sense in your program) and define it in deck.cpp.

For instance:

deck.h

```
extern Card GLOBAL_DECK[52];
```

deck.cpp

```
Card GLOBAL_DECK[52];
```

Now as for using a global, it is a much better approach to avoid globals, and pass references to an object that lives in a higher scope, or create the object on the heap and pass pointers or references to it (but you have to remember to delete it once you are finished with it).

For the question about where do you need your includes, you should be wrapping each header in include guards like this (replacing HEADER_NAME with the header file name, for instance hand.h becomes HAND_H:

```
#ifndef HEADER_NAME
#define HEADER_NAME

header contents

#endif //Some people like to put HEADER_NAME here but it isn't really necessary 
//unless you are using a lot of precompiler directives, which you shouldn't be
```

Then include the headers in files that need them. Hand and deck needs card, anything else depends on how you have used them. Since you haven't mentioned which complier/toolset you are using I can't give you specific instructions. But I would compile them by themselves and include what you need to get each file compiling. You may encounter circular dependencies, which means that A requires B to compile which requires A to compile (or a longer chain, but eventually it becomes circular), and you will need to research forward declarations and may need to use references and pointers to solve, or change your design.

Then you need to link the object files together to make an executable.  If you are using an integrated IDE like Visual Studio or code::blocks it will do it for you, but you might need to find out what your linker is or set up one if you are using a generic IDE like eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables (or constants) are declared at the top of a file, below the includes, but above any code.

So for this examples, I would write it simply like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deck.h>
#include <hand.h>
#include <card.h>

extern deck ... // If we want to use the deck constant anywhere in our program

int main ()
{
    ...
}
```

notice that I assumed here that deck is non-constant (which I think would not pose a problem).
But if you absolutely need to use a global constant, you can create a new file, name it deckConstant.cpp for example then write the following in this file :

```
namespace myGlobalConstant
{
    extern const deck ... // put the name of the constant you want
}
```

and create of course the file deckConstant.h :

```
#ifndef DECKCONSTANT_H
#define DECKCONSTANT_H

namespace myGlobalConstant
{
    extern const deck ...
}
#endif
```

then in the main.cpp file you just add :

```
#include <deckConstant.h>
using namespace myGlobalConstant
```

I hope I understood the question right.